# Django: ForeignKey on_delete SET_DEFAULT behavior

Tags: django

Let me please consider the following two models:

```
class Policy(models.Model):
        name = models.SlugField(max_length=256, blank = False, unique = True)
def default_policy():
        return Policy.objects.get(name='default').pk
class Item(models.Model):
        policy = models.ForeignKey('Policy', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=default_policy)
```

Everything works as expected except the one operation. I still can do the following without any exceptions:

```
p = Policy.objects.get(name='default')
p.delete()
```

And this produces orphaned `Item`s which were referring to "default" `Policy` object.
Unfortunately, this operation leads to integrity issue in database, because there are `Item`s which policy_id column now refers to missed record of `Policy` table.

How could I prevent this from happening? Deleting "default" `Policy` when no `Item`s refer to it is acceptable to me.

Comment: Consider using models.CASCADE for on_delete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to do conditional ForeignKey.on\_delete in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794103/possible-to-do-conditional-foreignkey-on-delete-in-django)

Answer (score 7):

It depends on your business requirements. Should every `Item` always point to a valid `Policy`? And what's the requirement from business point-of-view when a `Policy` gets deleted? Should the `Item`s pointing to it also be deleted? We don't know your requirements, so it's difficult to answer your question. These are your options from a technical perspective:

- Set `on_delete=CASCADE` if you want the `Item` to be deleted when the `Policy` is deleted
- Set `on_delete=PROTECT` if you don't want to allow any `Policy` to be deleted if there's still any `Item` pointing to it. In that case you'll have to `try: policy.delete(); except ProtectedError: ...` in your code to handle that situation.
- Set `on_delete=SET_DEFAULT` if you know your default policy will not be deleted (you could override the `delete` method on `Policy` to avoid deleting the default policy).
- Set `on_delete=SET_NULL` if an `Item` can have no `Policy`. That may be valid in certain business scenarios. But in this case you must also have `null=True`.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your scenario with `Django 4.1` and `sqlite`, and I got the exception you waited for!

But just to provide more customizability, especially in handling exceptions, the following code works with the mentioned environment:

```
from django.db import models
import django.db


def SET_DEFAULT_AND_PREVENT_DELETE_DEFAULT(collector, field, sub_objs, using):
    """
    ``sub_objs`` is the Queryset of Items that are affected by this delete.
    Hence, none of them should have referenced the default Policy (Otherwise,
    the default Policy is going to be deleted!).
    Also, if we are deleting an Item, there should be a default Policy to
    be set as the new Policy of Item.
    """
    try:
        default_policy = Policy.objects.get(name='default')
    except Policy.DoesNotExist:
        raise django.db.InternalError("You should have default policy before "
                                      "deleting a referenced policy")
    for item in sub_objs:
        if item.policy == default_policy:
            raise django.db.InternalError("You cannot delete default policy "
                                          "when there are items referencing it")

    collector.add_field_update(field, default_policy, sub_objs)


class Policy(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(max_length=256, blank=False, unique=True)


class Item(models.Model):
    policy = models.ForeignKey('Policy', on_delete=SET_DEFAULT_AND_PREVENT_DELETE_DEFAULT)
```