# Is there such a thing as a conditional "ON DELETE CASCADE" in Django?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

Is there a simple way, using `on_delete`, to delete the object containing a ForeignKey when that ForeignKey is deleted (like `models.CASCADE` would normally do) but just the ForeignKey relationship to `None` if some condition is met (like `models.SET_NULL` would normally do).

Here is some code:

```
class SomeThing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        related_name="things", 
        on_delete=models.CONDITIONAL_CASCADE,  # obviously this is wrong
    )
    is_private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

```
>>> user = User(username="bob").save()
>>> public_thing = SomeThing(is_private=False)
>>> private_thing = SomeThing(is_private=True)
>>> user.things.add(public_thing)
>>> user.things.add(private_thing)
>>> user.delete()
```

When `user` is deleted I would like `private_thing` to be deleted along w/ `user`, but `public_thing` to *not* be deleted and for `public_thing.user` to be set to `None`.

Thanks.

---

**edit:**

Thanks to @Jarad's suggestion, I wound up writing the following generic function:

```
def CONDITIONAL_CASCADE(collector, field, sub_objs, using, **kwargs):
    
    condition = kwargs.get("condition", {})
    default_value = kwargs.get("default_value", None)

    sub_objs_to_cascade = sub_objs.filter(**condition)
    sub_objs_to_set = sub_objs.exclude(**condition)

    models.CASCADE(collector, field, sub_objs_to_cascade, using)
    collector.add_field_update(field, default_value, sub_objs_to_set)
```

and using it like this:

```
CASCADE_PRIVATE_THINGS_ONLY = partial(
    CONDITIONAL_CASCADE,
    condition={"is_private": True},
    default_value=None
)
```

Comment: `on_delete=models.SET(func)` looks promising [models.SET](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET)

Comment: This is also helpful! [Possible to do conditional ForeignKey.on_delete in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794103/possible-to-do-conditional-foreignkey-on-delete-in-django)

Comment: @Jarad that link you sent helped a great deal.  I wound up doing something very similar.